# Android Client TCP

Tags: java, android, tcp

I have a simple Server TCP write in JAVA and I have a simple Client Android that connetted to the server, but when the server write on the BufferedStream the client can not read the message.

Everythings works to perfection if the server don't write on the Buffered Server->client but I'm not understanding because the client can not the buffered in input.

The client has a textedit and onu button for the send a written message in the textedit, but the message doesn't arrive to the server, but when the application on Android is forcibly close then the message arrive to the server. WHY?

Comment: All are right, but please provide code what have you tried earlier..

Answer (score 1):

Your last sentence lets me assume, that you are using a BufferedWriter or something like that, to send the data. If the size of the data you want to send is below the buffer size, the BufferedWriter simply buffers the data and waits for more data to send until it "thinks" "now I have enough data to send the message". You might want to call a flush(), if your message is ready to be sent.